# json_decode problems in php

Tags: json, url, decode

i use json_decode function to get some data from dynamic urls.
some urls are working fine inside the decode function, others are not.

for example:
this is working fine:

```
 $jsondata = file_get_contents("http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=&level=1&min=1&max=50&points=48000");
 $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

but when i change the 48000 to 45000, the decode is not working any more.
41000 is working fine again.

also.. when i add some other attributes after the points-attribute... the decode function does also not work anymore.

for example:

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents("http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=&level=1&min=1&max=50&points=20000&loc=32000007");
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

when i remove `&loc=32000007` it works again.

when you use direct the urls in the browser, all of them are working.
only the `json_decode` function is not working with some of them.

is there any limitation in the characters which you can use inside the `json_decode` function? is there any way to handle this?

your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok. i managed to get this problem solved.
here is one simple solution which can be adapted according to the requirements.
all characters which are listed inside the array will be replaced by character "?"

```
 $jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
 $tobecleaned = array("®");
 $jsondatacleaned = str_replace($tobecleaned, "?", $jsondata);
 $data = json_decode($jsondatacleaned, true);
```